How do I get a Cognito refresh token using Amplify?
My code, using Amplify v6:
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import { signIn, fetchAuthSession } from "aws-amplify/auth";

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        Cognito: {
            userPoolClientId: "xxx",
            userPoolId: "xxx",
        },
    },
});

await signIn({
    username: "xxx",
    password: "xxx",
});

const authSession = await fetchAuthSession();

console.log(authSession.tokens);

My hope was that this would return a refresh token, but authSession.tokens just contains accessToken, idToken, and signInDetails.
How do I get a refresh token?
